# Process unexpectedly closed with status: 1

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

Имеется selenium скрипт, при запуске которого должен открываться браузер, заходить на сайт и делать скрин

Скрипт работает на сервере

При запуске получаю вот такую ошибку

```
Process unexpectedly closed with status: 1
```

Как мне узнать более подробно о ней?

Может ли это быть связанно с тем, что на сервере отсутствует гуй?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
from PIL import Image


def get_screen(coinname, user):
    #chrome_path = 'C:\webdrivers\chromedriver'
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/home/schedude/webdriver/geckodriver')
    driver.get('https://ru.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol='+coinname+'USD')
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('wizard-tooltip-stop').click()
    sleep(1.5)
    elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.submenu.apply-common-tooltip').click()
    sleep(1.5)
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.send_keys('15')
    actions.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    actions.perform()
    #elem.send_keys('15')
    #elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    sv = driver.save_screenshot("{:%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S}.jpg".format(datetime.datetime.now()))
    user.path = sv
    user.save()
    driver.quit()

    def edit_photo(user):
        photo_path = user.path
        try:
            img = Image.open(photo_path)
            area = (45, 70, 720, 490)
            cropped_img = img.crop(area)
            cropped_img.show()
            img_path = cropped_img.save("{:%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S}.jpg".format(datetime.datetime.now()))
            user.path = img_path
            user.save()
        except:
            pass

    edit_photo(user)
```

Comment: *"Как мне узнать более подробно о ней?"* -- не используйте пустой `except: pass` (за исключением особых особых случаев)

Comment: @jfs убрал эту часть кода, но к сожалению это не помогло, ошибка появляется до выполнения этой ф-ции. На самом старте где-то

Comment: это просто комментарий, а не ответ. Чтобы не отвлекаться, уберите из вопроса весь код, который не нужен, чтобы воспроизвести проблему. К примеру, достаточно импорт и webdriver.Firefox() строчку оставить? (чтобы ошибку получить). Попробуйте headless режим. Включите дополнительную трассировку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась при запуске в `headless mode`

```
options = Options()
#set headless mode
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, executable_path='/home/schedude/webdriver/geckodriver')
driver.get('https://ru.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=BTCUSD')
```

Cпасибо всем за ответы и помощь!

Answer (score -1):

Зря убрали except! Он как раз и нужен, чтобы отлавливать ошибки. Укажите в нем ту ощибку, которую он должен ловить и он вам пригодится. ;) Еще можно поковырять все это дело дебаггером pdb + можно заморочиться логгированием с помощью модуля [logging.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html)